# Laravel takes too long to load views

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I have a LEMP stack setup using vagrant and virtual box on a windows Machine.
php is version 7.0, Nginx is version 1.4.6. I've allocated a RAM of 768mb to the guest machine(Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS)

On the guest machine, I've installed and configured composer as instructed on the Laravel documentation page. Using the Laravel installer, I installed Laravel in the www directory of my host machine `laravel new commerce` So the path to my laravel installation looks something like this `/vagrant/www/commerce`

In my Nginx config file, I configured Nginx to serve files from this location `/vagrant/www/commerce/public` and to redirect all request to the index page `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`

In the browser(chrome) when I test to see if everything is working fine, it takes about 4-5 seconds for the Laravel landing page to display in the browser. This is the same for safari and firefox. I shut down the guest machine and restarted it several times but the landing page still takes about 4-5 seconds to display.

I stumbled upon a post somewhere online where I was told to install debugbar. I installed debugbar successfully. When I tested in the browser again, It took about 16 seconds for the landing page to display. The strange thing here is that debugbar logged no messages. Frustrating.

Another solution suggested slowlog. So, first, i uninstalled debugbar and in my guest machine, i configured slowlog to track slow requests. I set a timeout of 10s. When i checked the slow.log file in `/var/log` I got what's in the image below [slow.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbe7x.png) I can't seem to make any sense out of this. please i need help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On the web browser developer tools net tab what is displaying? You can check what is slowing down your web page, you can try with Firebug on Firefox.

Comment: The debugbar does slow the request down more because of the monitoring. However, you can also see what is slowing down your request in the `timeline` tab. Could you post a screenshot of this?

Comment: Debugbar provides enough information about whats happening when a page is rendered, maybe you didn't use it correctly, also check configurations on environment the Laravel is running.

Comment: Just create a test controller action and view and do some timings. If the time it takes from the action start to the route generation is indeed the problem, this will let you know.

Comment: @troyer i just checked the network tab of firefox, in the cause column, i see `js document` i've checked the `welcome.blade.php` file in the views folder. Its not requesting any javascript. I'm confused.

Comment: @Jerodev here's what debugbar shows ![debugbar log](http://imgur.com/ec9o1Fk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and enabling NFS for folder sharing fixed it. Add NFS to **~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml**

```
folders:
- map: ~/www/commerce
  to: /vagrant/www/commerce
  type: "nfs"
```

And then provision your server.

```
vagrant halt
vagrant up --provision
```

Comment: I'm not using homestead

Comment: Homestead is just a wrapper around Vagrant (which you're already using) so you might want to try it. It sets up everything for you, so the likelihood of configuration problems like this will be less.

Comment: i just did that. `config.vm.synced_folder "./www/commerce", "/vagrant/www/commerce", type:"nfs"` But it made no difference still.

Comment: It could be a configuration issue with the VM. The advantage of Homestead is that the box is preconfigured. I would personally try to use the preconfigured homestead box since you're already using vagrant -- and it's a simple "vagrant box add laravel/homestead." If it works, you can rule out a time-consuming hunt for configuration issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jasonBoss although i didn't use nfs. i change it to rsync. i followed the instructions in this link [link](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/rsync-vagrant-15-file-performance-windows-dev)